# how to convert python image matrix to one dimentional vector

Tags: python, image-processing

i have an image matrix

```
    [[0.12843137 0.13039216 0.13235294 ... 0.13529412 0.13333333 0.12647059]
     [0.13235294 0.12941176 0.13137255 ... 0.13137255 0.12941176 0.1254902 ]
     [0.13333333 0.13431373 0.13921569 ... 0.13333333 0.13431373 0.12745098]
     ...
     [0.15098039 0.14411765 0.14509804 ... 0.09901961 0.10098039 0.09901961]
     [0.14215686 0.15490196 0.14901961 ... 0.09509804 0.1        0.1       ]
     [0.15196078 0.14901961 0.15686275 ... 0.10294118 0.09803922 0.10196078]]
```

i want to convert it to one dim vector through column concatenation? i tried

```
     rescaled_Image=rescale(image, scale=(0.5, 0.5))
     one_dim_vector = np.ravel(rescaled_Image)
     print(one_dim_vector).
```

but output not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
one_dim_vector = image.flatten('F')
```

Flatten with Fortran-style, please find more in [this document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.flatten.html)

Comment: i need column vector through column concatenation of the matrix

Comment: I still don't get what you mean, can you make a simple example with a simple 9x9 matrix?

Comment: Thanks Toby i got answer.     rescaled_Image=rescale(image, scale=(0.5, 0.5))
            vector = np.ravel(rescaled_Image)
            one_dim_vector=vector.reshape(-1, 1)

Comment: where was the rescale (in rescale(image, scale=(0.5, 0.5)))  function come from?